# How to adjust TPM lockout?

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

I use bitlocker in combination with a TPM on Lenovo T410. The TPM seems to trigger a lock-out after one incorrect password attempt which annoys me to no end. How can I adjust the TPM lockout threshold?

Also, restarting the computer does not help with lock-out :(

tpm.msc does't seem to have such options.

Answer (score 2):

Answer - you can't :( There is no way to adjust the lockout. The only thing to do is to try and reset the lockout to prevent it from ballooning exponentially.